# Wrong item checked when filtering ListView in android

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, filtering

I have a ListView with multiple choice entries where some are checked from the beginning using

```
setItemChecked(position, true);
```

I combine this with the filtering option

```
setTextFilterEnabled(true)
```

so it's easy to find a specific entry in the list.

The problem is that when I filter the list the entries switch position in the list view. Take for example three entries: 'A', 'B' and 'C' where 'C' is checked beforehand (i.e. the entry at position 3 in the list). When I type a 'C' on the keyboard, only the 'C' entry is displayed (as intended). Now 'C' is not checked anymore, since the entry has moved from the checked position 3 to the unchecked position 1 in the list.

This behavior leads to some not very welcome effects in the app. Is there a way to "move the selection with the filtering", i.e. bind the checked state to the entry and not to its initial position in the list? Or do I need to find a new approach?

Thanks,

Linus

Comment: Suffering from the same problem. I know it's been long, but did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: @liorry: I don't really remember, but I think I went with the suggestion in the accepted answer. Too long ago :)

Comment: haha OK. I though maybe you can share the code... I used the suggestion but something is not working for me... oh well, Thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maintain a list of the selected items, and whenever the list is repopulated check if that `id` (not position) exists in the list, and set as selected.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this behaviour is because ListView holds the position as a reference to selected items. This means that even for adapters with stable IDs the selection is bound to the position (which has been filtered out in your case).
As suggested, implement some custom map/set for holding IDs that are checked and feed them to the adapter.