# Android: Wrong item checked when filtering listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm suffering from the same issue as this question: [Wrong item checked when filtering ListView in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487821/wrong-item-checked-when-filtering-listview-in-android)

As suggested in the above question, I have an Hashset holding all the selectedIds, but I can't figure out how to use it when the cursor is repopulating the checked items.

My issue is only cosmetic - for example:

- "Facebook" is located at the 5th position in the unfiltered list.
- User searched for "face", only "Facebook" appears in the 1st position in the filtered list.
- User checks "Facebook" as selected and goes back to the unfiltered list.
- The checked item is the 1st item in the list and not "Facebook" (positioned 5th).

**Note:**
Except this issue, everything else works great.
For example, "delete" will delete the right items because I use the selectedIds to do it (even if the checked items are wrong).

**Single click on a list item:**

```
OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                //gets the Bookmark ID of selected position
                    Cursor cursor = (Cursor)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    String bookmarkID = cursor.getString(0);

                    boolean currentlyChecked = checkedStates.get(position);
                    checkedStates.set(position, !currentlyChecked);

                    if (!selectedIds.contains(bookmarkID)) {

                        selectedIds.add(bookmarkID);
                        selectedLines.add(position);

                    } else {

                        selectedIds.remove(bookmarkID);
                        selectedLines.remove(position);


                        }

            }
        };
```

**Inside the Cursor: - this is where the problem lies.**

This repopulates the checked items - the problem is it does it by position (pos) and what was the right position of the item in the filtered list, is not its position in the unfiltered list - resulting in a wrongly marked item.

```
CheckedTextView markedItem = (CheckedTextView) row.findViewById(R.id.btitle);
markedItem.setChecked(checkedStates.get(pos));
```

Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue.
As suggested in the question I added to mine, when you populate the checkboxes, the other List/Hashset should determine whether to mark item as checked or not.

Using my code:

```
//first you will need to get the current item ID
String bookmarkID = cursor.getString(0);

//Then, check if the current ID is in the selectedIds hash/list
//If true - mark current item view as checked, else - uncheck.
        CheckedTextView markedItem = (CheckedTextView) row.findViewById(R.id.btitle);
        if (selectedIds.contains(new String(bookmarkID))) {
            markedItem.setChecked(true);

        } else {
            markedItem.setChecked(false);
}
```

Really hope this will help anyone! :)

Comment: I am a bit confused about implementing this. I have a SimpleCursorAdapter with a listview. How are you initializing checkedStates, selectedIds and selectedLines?

Also, will the list/hashset mentioned in the answer to determine item marked as checked or not, need a Custom Adapter or I can use a SimpleCursorAdapter?

Comment: @movingahead can't really post the code here (solved question)... either start a new question or email me (my nick at gmail) and i'll try to help.

Comment: I asked a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399941/implementing-a-listview-with-multiple-select-with-filter-using-a-cursor-adapter Will be great if you can help.

Comment: @movingahead posted an answer there.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be simply that you ListView does not know the data set changed? Call notifyDatSetChanged() on your adapter to let it know.

```
my_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This will force a redraw of the list, with the updated data.

Comment: It knows. unfortunately that's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

- To selecte an item in list view after filtering, at the beginning, I got wrong item because I used this:

  ```
  ItemData item = listItems.get(position);
  ```

The correct way should be like this:

```
    ItemData item = (ItemData) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

- To delete an item after filtered, I have tried this:

  ```
  for(int i=0;i<listItems.size();i++){
      if(listItems.get(i).getItemID() == item.getItemID()){
          listItems.remove(i);
          myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     }
  }
  ```

But that didn't worked because my custom adapter. In my custom adapter, to use filter, I have two listItems:

```
    ArrayList<ItemData> listItemsToShow = new ArrayList< ItemData >();
    ArrayList< ItemData > listItemsBackup = new ArrayList< ItemData >();
```

So to delete an item, I added new method in my custom adapter:

```
    public void deleteItem(String itemID) {
    for (int i = 0; i < listItemsToShow.size(); i++) {
        if (listItemsToShow.get(i).getId().equals(itemID)) {
            listItemsToShow.remove(i);
            break;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < listItemsBackup.size(); i++) {
        if (listItemsBackup.get(i).getId().equals(itemID)) {
            listItemsBackup.remove(i);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Finally to delete an item in list view:

```
    subjectBaseAdapter.deleteItem(subject.getId());
    subjectBaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Hope this help